# How to call JavaScript function from body of HTML document on pageload-complete

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have some JavaScript (code to initialize Google Maps if you're interested) that I'm forced to include within the `<body></body>` tags of an html document and I would like to have one of my methods trigger on page-load complete. The catch is that I don't have access to the `<body>` html tag, so I can't do:

```
<body onload="foo()">
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? I realize this is a ridiculous scenario.

Comment: use jquery it has a document ready and then you can do functions based on the load of the body

Comment: @Laurence I first thought of using jQuery but the OP might not have the ability to include external scripts so I opted to use DOM as my example.  Felix had a good solution as well.  All solutions, jQuery, DOM, and explicit event attachment are all workable and usable solutions.  @Casey it really depends on your limitations but jQuery really is the ideal way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on when the code is run, attach the handler with JavaScript:

```
if(window.onload) {
    var _existing = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
        _existing();
        foo();
    };
}
else {
    window.onload = foo;
}
```

As you seem to have no control over the page we have to be a bit more careful. Other JavaScript might already have set an event handler. To be a good citizen, we don't just overwrite the event handler, but keep a reference to it in case it exists.

However other JavaScript code could overwrite this again.

The best way would be to use the more advanced event handling methods [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) (W3C) and [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (IE).

For more information about event handling I suggest to read the [excellent articles on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Comment: Beat me by 1 second, but yours is more complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can programattically attach events using the DOM.

```
// Function to add event listener to body 

function addLoadFn() 
{ 
   var body = document.getElementById("body"); 
   body.addEventListener("load", myOnloadListener, false); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a simple example SRM?

Comment: It should be `body.addEventListener("load", myOnloadListener, false);` (without `on` ;)). You need `"onload"` for `attachEvent` in IE.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = foo;

function foo(){
  alert("page loaded!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you can use `$(document).ready`:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });
```

See this [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29).